# OpenSearch fails to create even with service linked role - Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-elasticsearch

I am deploying a Opensearch Domain in Cloudformation, however even though I am creating a service linked role for OpenSearch it still fails to create, with the error in the image below:

[image]

The template is as:

```
OpenSearchRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::ServiceLinkedRole'
    Properties:
      AWSServiceName: es.amazonaws.com
      Description: 'Role for ES to access resources in my VPC'

  OpenSearchDomain:
    Type: "AWS::OpenSearchService::Domain"
    DependsOn: [OpenSearchRole]
    Properties:
      Required properties
```

As this happen to anyone else, if so how am I able to solve this?
I'm not sure if this might be because the service linked role takes sometime to propagate or something like that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Related issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47229247/validationexception-before-you-can-proceed-you-must-enable-a-service-linked-ro). Seems like propagation could be the cause.